# xcode 5 horizontal scroll doesn't work

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview, horizontal-scrolling

who can help me with this code? Simply it doesn't work, same as ALL I have tried for vertical scrolling. I'm starting to think that my Xcode emulator has something wrong. Here's the code:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 400)];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
[scroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
{

    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1222, 400)];
    [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"panorama_orizzonte_medio_big.jpg"]];
    [scroll addSubview:imageview];
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
}
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you trying to scroll the image?

Comment: Yes, I followed a tutorial in order to horizontal-scroll image. I followed step by step it but my simulator doesn't scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set the `UIImageView`, you need to set the `scrollView`'s `contentSize` to that of your `imageView`'s, so, something like this:

```
[scroll setContentSize:imageview.frame.size];
```

Comment: First, Xcode suggests me to change "scrollview" in "UIScrollView" and "imageView" with "imageview". Plus, on "setContentSize" I get an issue: no know class method for selector SetContentSize.

Comment: well, I just put generic object names in there. You should use your own names. As with `setContentSize`, you can use `scroll.contentSize`

Comment: Ok, I'm a jackass. I didn't click mouse button while scrolling, I'm tired... Thanks for help! :-)